# Load different CSS file with jQuery.browser for rails 3.1

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass

I want load a css or scss file of my rails 3.1 project with **Jquery.browser** detection.

In web page http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/ I can see how set property css for example:

```
if ( $.browser.msie ) {
$("#div ul li").css( "display","inline" );
 } else {
$("#div ul li").css( "display","inline-table" );
 }
```

But I want can loading a **CSS or SCSS FILe** that I have in my project rails 3.1 depend if is browser opera, firefox, chrome, safari, ie...etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically load different css files with:

```
$("<link/>", {
   rel: "stylesheet",
   type: "text/css",
   href: "/styles/yourcss.css"
}).appendTo("head");
```